# href vs Link React? JS is not loading based on HTML tags

Tags: html, reactjs, navigation, html-lists

I am trying to understand if this is a REACT or css issue e.g.. I have the following code below in React component:

```
       <div className="left">
        <Link to="/" className="brand">
          <img src={Logo} alt="" />
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className="right">
        <div className="primary-nav">
          <ul className="navigation">
            <li className="active">
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </dic>
```

The first link does not work, mainly if the Link element is wrapped in Div or any other it looks like it is not reloading the page correctly. E.g. Some .js files are not loaded, pictures in the dom, hence page is not working properly. While if I use the second link all works as expected. I don't see a difference in React, hence looks to me a CSS issue?

Once I wrapped the first div element as per below, this worked.

```
      <div className="primary-nav">
        <ul className="left">
          <li>
            <Link to="/index.html" className="brand">
              <img src={Logo} alt="" />
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Moreover if I replace this Link to a and href element then this works as well!

I am not sure if this would be related as Css issue, and if so, then why would that affect the page reload? Or if this is something straightforward React experts see and is easily fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't consider Your React code as a Simple HTML . Actually the thing is That react Uses a JSX code . that mean it bit different Than original html . yaa that is true that at the last React convert jsx code into a Html . but internally react manage a JSX elements .

Now We are Going to your Point href and Link are different thing cause href is html property that uses html default javascript or you can say core javascript but Link mean you are tracking something or we can say manage something using your own javascript . 
See Notice One Thing that when you are using a href your page will refresh and when you are using a [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) than it may be it will not refresh your whole Dom depends on your coding but when your are working with react you need to use Link for better practice . it will also improve a quality of your web application.

Comment: Ok this is bit more clear. So why would my page loose img if I use Link, but have the img elements displayed if I use href? If it is not re-loading, then shouldn't it mean the img should be cashed? E.g. when using paginations, the first page show pictures, then second does not, once I come back it does not show any pictures anymore, refreshing the page, displayes me the pictures again.

Comment: yes its true your react app makes a cashed data . that means when you open a site once your website will be store in cashed memory . and for your image issue that i need to see what is happening in coding flow . [link](www.orfenza.com) see this site is created by me and you can see if you visit at once than whenever go to second time it will not take load that much that means it uses your cashed memory

Comment: Very nice page, you have build there! :). It seems like it is because of a JS field, though would there be a difference if I specify the source as `src="./path/img.jpg"` or `src="{require(./path/img.jpg)}"` ?

Comment: Bro <img alt="timer" src={require('./images/timer.png')} /> try this one on above code you didn't quote your path , and verify my answer if you like